# Reduce/remove spacing after header on Google Sites

Tags: google-classic-sites

I have a problem with spacing between header on my Google Site. There is a lot of space after the subheadings. This makes the heading "detached" form the text, and makes it harder to scan and read.

The only settings I have found concerning the headers are in `Manage Site > Themes, Color & Fonts > Content Area`, but I am only able to change font and font size in there. Not line or paragraph spacing. [This page](https://sites.google.com/site/siteshelphowtos/google-sites-instructions/Basics/linespacing) talks about doing it manually with HTML every single time, but that is kind of against the point of using a CMS like google sites.

### Examples:

This is the current layout:

[image]

I am looking for something more like this mock:

[image]

### Update:

This could be fixed by changing the css attribute `margin-bottom`. It does however seems like [that is not possible](http://kbase.icbconsulting.com/html-javascript/tips-for-using-google-sites/how-to-use-css-in-google-sites). Related to [this question](http://kbase.icbconsulting.com/html-javascript/tips-for-using-google-sites/how-to-use-css-in-google-sites).